# How can I set NSTextField value while timer is working?

Tags: swift, macos, textfield, nstextfield, appkit

I wanna make a timer and there is some function that set the timer label (exactly `NSTextField`) while the timer is working. but that doesn't work!

Firstly, I implemented a function that displays time.

```
func timeDisplay() {

    print("isTimerStart: \(TimerController.isTimerStart)")

    let timerSecond = TimerController.secondDuration

    self.minuteTextField.stringValue = String(format: "%02d", (timerSecond / 60))
    print("minuteTextField: \(String(self.minuteTextField.integerValue))")

    self.secondTextFieled.stringValue = ": \(String(format: "%02d", TimerController.secondDuration % 60))"
    print("secondTextField: \(String(self.secondTextFieled.stringValue))")

}
```

I add `timeDisplay()` at `viewDidLoad()` to test that function.

If `timeDisplay()` is triggered by `viewDidLoad()` or just button clicking, IT WORKS perfectly!

but if I start timer and `timeDisplay()` is triggered by `@objc` function, it doesn't work displaying error that `minuteTextField` (or `secondTextField`) is optional value so I can't set the value at `NSTextField` while the timer is on whereas I can set the value by just button :/

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

OH PLEASE HELP ME!

Answer (score 0):

To update your TextField text you have to manually change the text for every sec. you can use Timer to schedule this triggering. check out the following code. I have tested. You have to use the main thread to update the display value.

Note:- The Timer need to be set after the initialization of textFeild.

```
    class TimerViewController: UIViewController {
    var timerTextField : UITextField? = nil
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.timerTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: 400, width: 200, height: 50))

        self.view.addSubview(timerTextField!)

        //It should be started after textFeild init.
        self.startTimer()
    }
    func startTimer(){
        //MARK:- This Timer will refresh Text Feild for every 1 sec.
               Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(timeDisplay), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    @objc func timeDisplay(){
        //MARK:- This Example to display Device time. You can change this code as per your need.

       let date = Date()
       let calendar = Calendar.current
       let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
       let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
       let sec = calendar.component(.second, from: date)

       let timeStr = "\(hour) : \(minutes) : \(sec)"
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
         self.timerTextField?.text = timeStr
       }
    }
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        self.stopTimer()
    }

    func stopTimer(){ Timer.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: timeDisplay())
    }
}
```

Output:-

[image]

Comment: First of all the question is for MacOS not for iOS. Secondly, even your code is not working fine, See how the time changes from 36 seconds to 37... it is too fast.